# Can a telegram bot block a specific user?

Tags: telegram-bot, spam-prevention

I have a telegram bot that for any received message runs a program in the server and sends its result back. But there is a problem! If a user sends too many messages to my bot(spamming), it will make server so busy! 
Is there any way to block the people whom send more than 5 messages in a second and don't receive their messages anymore? (using telegram API!)

Comment: No, you can't. API does not provide this feature. Just make a local block list of users whom the bot will ignore.

Comment: I want those users' messages don't even exist in the json file which I download from telegram server! Anyway, it's ok if there is no other way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly I have to say that Telegram Bot API does not have such a capability itself, Therefore you will need to implement it on your own and all you need to do is:

1. Count the number of the messages that a user sends within a second which won't be so easy without having a database. But if you have a database with a table called Black_List and save all the messages with their sent-time in another table, you'll be able to count the number of messages sent via **one specific ChatID** in a pre-defined time period(In your case; 1 second) and check if the count is bigger than 5 or not, **if the answer was YES you can insert that ChatID to the Black_List table.**
2. Every time the bot receives a message it must run a database query to see that the sender's chatID exists in the Black_List table or not. If it exists it should continue its own job and ignore the message(Or even it can send an alert to the user saying: "You're blocked." which I think can be time consuming).

Note that as I know the current telegram bot API doesn't have the feature to stop receiving messages but as I mentioned above you can ignore the messages from spammers.

> **In order to save time**, You should avoid making a database connection
>   every time the bot receives an update(message), instead **you can load
>   the ChatIDs that exist in the Black_List to a DataSet and update the
>   DataSet right after the insertion of a new spammer ChatID to the
>   Black_List table.** This way the number of the queries will reduce
>   noticeably.

Comment: I recommend using redis for implementing this scenario

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi but we can still ban a user in a supergroup/channel, according to https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.editBanned, right?

Comment: @stckvrw I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it by this mean:

```
# Using the ttlcache to set a time-limited dict. you can adjust the ttl.
ttl_cache = cachetools.TTLCache(maxsize=128, ttl=60)


def check_user_msg_frequency(message):
    print(ttl_cache)
    msg_cnt = ttl_cache[message.from_user.id]
    if msg_cnt > 3:
        now = datetime.now()
        until = now + timedelta(seconds=60*10)
        bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, until_date=until)
        

def set_user_msg_frequency(message):
    if not ttl_cache.get(message.from_user.id):
        ttl_cache[message.from_user.id] = 1
    else:
        ttl_cache[message.from_user.id] += 1
```

With these to functions above, you can record how many messages sent by any user in the period. If a user's messages sent more than expected, he would be restricted.

Then, every handler you called should call these two functions:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def handle_start_help(message):
    set_user_msg_frequency(message)
    check_user_msg_frequency(message)
```

I'm using `pyTelegramBotAPI` this module to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but here is another simple solution that doesn't use a Db:

- Create a ConversationState class to attach to each telegram Id when they start to chat with the bot
- Then add a LastMessage DateTime variable to the ConversationState class
- Now every time you receive a message check if enought time has passed from the LasteMessage DateTime, if not enought time has passed answer with a warning message.

You can also implement a timer that deletes the conversation state class if you are worried about performance.

Comment: Parties are good even if you arrive a bit late. XD However, I was wondering although this solution works for a small bot, it's against the factors of [12-factor app](https://12factor.net/) and therefore not so scalable.

Comment: @MaGaroo against which factor would it be? Wouldn't checking a simple hash map for each message be more efficent than doing a query ( as suggested in the highest answer)?

Comment: Of course that's more efficient, but it's against "Execute the app as one or more stateless processes" rule as mentioned [here](https://12factor.net/processes). That's because defining `ConversationState` makes the process stateful, and we won't be able to scale the number of processes.

It's impossible to share this dictionary among multiple processes without a backing service, and if we don't share it, there may be odd situations in which a process has blocked a user and another one hasn't.